# I would like to update permissions of a document library folder via a 2010 workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, designer-workflow

I have a workflow running on a list. When an item is changed, it needs to look for a folder in a separate document library that shares the name of the item. It then needs to update the permissions for that folder.

I am having trouble accomplishing this. I can update permissions for individual documents but I have not been able to reference the folder.

I attempted to `Update List Item'` in the document library and reference the list item where `Name` (Field) in the document library is equal to `Title` field in my list but I have not had any luck.

Any insight is super appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be disappointed.

Per my knowledge, currently, we cannot update permission of a folder using SharePoint Designer workflow.

For updating the permission of a folder, you need to edit it manually.